# Can't open downloaded PDF file on OS X Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, pdf

When I open a downloaded PDF file, it says I have to choose an application.

Nothing from the list of applications that comes up works to open the file.

Comment: Which web browser are you using? Which applications have you tried when opening a *.pdf file?

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck "recommended apps" and search for *Preview*.

Can you view it if you select it in *Finder* and press the *spacebar* (to toggle Quick View)?

Answer (score 0):

Download the [Adobe Reader](http://get.adobe.com/reader/) to oepn and read PDF files easily on a Mac.

Comment: Would you recommend the same to someone on Windows who already has a PDF viewer and gets the equivalent "unknown file type" message?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I'm also sure that's not related.  @brenda didn't mention that s/he already had a PDF viewer.

Comment: It's called [Preview](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preview_(Mac_OS)) and comes with the OS. If you don't have it, you have done something very wrong.